# How to pass value from jsp to some methods in controller on click of certain option?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl

I am a newbie iam using jstl and spring,here i am having a jsp which fetch all the products like car,bike,cycle from database and i retrived all the products added in arraylist using jstl.Now in jsp i am having certain option like getlicense, getproduct on click of getlicense it should navigate to the method getlicense in controller from there it should navigate to getlicense.jsp.But the method getlicense in controller i have to pass certain values(like license information,license no) of my products (car,bike,cycle). Please help me resolving this issue
This my jsp here in license option i need to pass the values of  partnumber
to a method in modelandview

```
            <td class="listData" valign="top" width="14%">${suites.partNumber}</td>
            <td class="listData" valign="top" width="20%">${suites.assetDescription}</td>
            <td class="listData" valign="top" width="20$">${suites.assetNumber}</td>
            <td class="listData" valign="top" width="10$">  
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${empty suites.licenseType}">
                <c:out value="Not Available" />
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <c:out value="${suites.licenseType}" />
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>

            </td>

            <td class="listData" valign="top" width="15%">
                <a href="/webapp/servicerequest.create_SR.framework">
                    Submit Service Request
                </a>
            </td>

            <td class="listData" valign="top" width="11%">${suites.registeredDate}</td>
            <td class="listData" valign="top" width="11%">${suites.endDate}</td>



            <td class="listData" valign="top" width="10%" align="center">
                <a href="/webapp/licensing/licenseOptions.jsp">
                    <img src="/licensing/images/1443_LICENSE_OPTIONS.gif" alt="License Options" border="0"/>
                </a>

                <a href="/webapp/ecommerce.add_item.framework?PART_NUMBER=${suites.partNumber}&entitlementId=${suites.entitlementId}&ITEM_TYPE=${suites.assetType}&QUANTITY=1&RETURN_URL=/licensing/getSuiteList.sp&attribName=ENTITLEMENT_ID&licenseType=${suites.licenseType}">
                    <img src="/licensing/images/purchase.gif" alt="Purchase More Seats" border="0"/>
                </a>
            </td>
```

Comment: Please provide source code, tests, punctuation, CR, capital letters, indentation and details.

Comment: Yes. Please be more specific. Put as much of code as you can. If you do this, I will answer for sure. :-)

Comment: Being a newbie isn't a good enough excuse for a poorly written question!

Comment: @JapanTrivedi  Please check my above jsp code i cannot include the methods here

Comment: can you paste your spring mapping info as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from your problem is you need to access the PART_NUMBER passed in URL in your controller method.

For this you should add one parameter in your controller method to access the variable. Like below mentioned code.

```
@RequestParam String PART_NUMBER
```

Hope this helps you. If you have any other questions then be more specific.

Cheers.